# Parquet write to gcs is not queryable by bigquery in nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, parquet, parquetjs

i'm using [parquetjs](https://github.com/ironSource/parquetjs) to create parquet files and push to `google cloud storage`.

Problem is that bigquery cannot read the data from file but when i use `parquet-tools` everything looks healthy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just pass `useDataPageV2: false` as option to `parquet.ParquetWriter.openFile(...)`

Like this:

```js
const writer = await parquet.ParquetWriter.openFile(schema, filename, { useDataPageV2: false })
```

Comment: I had to search in github's repo to find it. incase you are stuck and using aws/s3/athena you can use the same solution. for more info visit: https://github.com/ironSource/parquetjs/issues/124